# How to build a dynamic URL with ampersands

Tags: xquery, urlencode

I have to build a dynamic url in XQuery. I have a hardcoded url. Part of the url should  be built from a variable. How do I build that url? I am not able to use concat in XQuery because the first half of the url has special characters (ampersands).

The value `ceiatlpaqer055.coxinc.com` in the below url is dynamic and should be populated from a different variable. How Do I build this url in XQuery?

The URL is given below:

```
http://axiomweb604.testinc.com:8080/arsys/forms/axiom_7_6_4/SHR%3ALandingConsole/Default+Administrator+View/?mode=search&F304255500=AST:ComputerSystem&F1000000076=FormOpenNoAppList&F303647600=SearchTicketWithQual&F304255610=%27Name%27%3D%22ceiatlpaqer055.coxinc.com%22
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a special character, so you have to escape it. Using the XML entity syntax this can be replaced by `&amp;`. So you can in fact concat this string, e.g. by doing

```
"http://axiomweb604.testinc.com:8080/arsys/forms/axiom_7_6_4/SHR%3ALandingConsole/Default+Administrator+View/?mode=search&amp;F304255500=AST:ComputerSystem&amp;F1000000076=FormOpenNoAppList&amp;F303647600=SearchTicketWithQual&amp;F304255610=%27Name%27%3D%22"  || "ceiatlpaqer055.coxinc.com" || "%22"
```

or

```
concat("http://axiomweb604.testinc.com:8080/arsys/forms/axiom_7_6_4/SHR%3ALandingConsole/Default+Administrator+View/?mode=search&amp;F304255500=AST:ComputerSystem&amp;F1000000076=FormOpenNoAppList&amp;F303647600=SearchTicketWithQual&amp;F304255610=%27Name%27%3D%22", "ceiatlpaqer055.coxinc.com", "%22")
```